# Change system locale permanently

Tags: r, windows

I am trying to change the system locale in r studio.

I used this code:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```

But when I restart Rstudio it reverts back to the previous locale

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Do you want to set the locale *for the entire system* or just for R (or RStudio) sessions?

Comment: Just for R (RStudio) sessions

Comment: In that case, the answer by Waldi should work.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You could create or edit `.Rprofile`, at user's level, or at project's level, [see](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/360047157094-Managing-R-with-Rprofile-Renviron-Rprofile-site-Renviron-site-rsession-conf-and-repos-conf).
For all R sessions (and hence RStudio sessions), this should work:

```
file.edit(file.path("~", ".Rprofile"))
```

add in `.Rprofile`:

```
Sys.setlocale("LC_ALL","English")
```

Comment: An equivalent (but more general ?) solution is to use the `etc/` directory each R installation has and to set `Rprofile.site`.  Or. of you wish use `Renviron.site` which can use the short `LC_ALL=English` form as could `~/.Renviron`.  It all amounts to the same: set the env var _when R starts_ as it cannot be set later.  All this is detailed in `help(Startup)` which has been referenced a few times here over the years.